# Multiple named inputs in Snakefile

Tags: python-3.x, snakemake

I want to make a pipeline that looks like this:

1. For each dataset extract some features
2. Make a unique list of all features
3. Extract the unique list from all the original datasets.

Here is a basic example of where I am

```
input_dict = {"data1": "/path/to/data1", "data2": "/path/to/data2"}

rule all:
    input: 
        expand('data/{dataset}.processed', dataset=input_dict.keys())

rule extract_master:
    output:
        'data/{dataset}.processed'
    input:
        master = rules.master_list.output, dataset = lambda wildcards: input_dict[wildcards.dataset]
    shell:
        "./extract_master.py --input {input.dataset} --out {output} --master {input.master}"

rule master_list:
    output:
        'data/master.txt'
    input:
        expand('data/{dataset}.chunk', dataset=input_dict.keys())
    shell:
        './master_list.py --input {input} --output {output}'

rule get_chunk:
    input:
        lambda wildcards: input_dict[wildcards.dataset]
    output:
        'data/{dataset}.chunk'
    shell:
        "./get_chunk.py --input {input} --output {output}"
```

I get an error:

```
'Rules' object has no attribute 'master_list'
```

I don't know how to specify two named inputs, where each input is not a simple string. If there is syntax I can use for the `input` section in the `extract_master` rule to fix this, that would be great. Otherwise, any thoughts on a better approach would be gladly received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Importantly, be aware that referring to rule a here requires that rule a was defined above rule b in the file, since the object has to be known already. This feature also allows to resolve dependencies that are ambiguous when using filenames.

[Source](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#rule-dependencies)

That is, in your example, `rule master_list` should be defined before `rule extract_master`.